# How to remove default routes from WebApi?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I can't found a way to remove default route paths for my Mobile service project based on WebApi. It generates routes such as "/api/{controller}/{id}" and "/tables/{controller}/{id}" which I don't want to provide for client apps. Instead of this I am mapping such route - "/api_v1/{controller}/{id}" and want to keep it as one possible route to access data.

Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        // Use this class to set configuration options for your mobile service
        ConfigOptions options = new ConfigOptions();
        options.LoginProviders.Add(typeof(CustomLoginProvider));            

        // Use this class to set WebAPI configuration options
        HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options));

        // add login provider            
        config.SetIsHosted(true);


        //foreach (var route in config.Routes)            
        //    Console.WriteLine(route.ToString());
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "api_v1",
              routeTemplate: "api_v1/{controller}/{id}",
              defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, } );

        //Create the object of particular router
        string result = "";
        foreach (var r in config.Routes)
            result += r.ToString();
        // This does not remove any route. 
        // Also there is no 'Name' property for Route to know exact match               
        config.Routes.Remove("api");
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I call config.Routes.Remove("") for every possible route i have and it removes only one name "tables". But "api" route is still there.

```
        ServiceConfig.Config.Routes.Remove("DefaultApi");   // not removed any
        ServiceConfig.Config.Routes.Remove("api");    // not removed any route
        ServiceConfig.Config.Routes.Remove("tables");  // this works!
```

How to remove default 'api' route?

Comment: There's nothing that generates "default" routes in WebAPI (especially with "tables" prefix). There should be something in your code (or any library you use) that sets them up.

Comment: The project created from "Azure Mobile Service" template and somewhere it generates 15 default routes, that i see in debbuger.

Comment: Have you tried looking in `ServiceConfig`?

Comment: Where it is please? Nothing related in Web.config or Global.asax or any file in project

Comment: You're calling it in this line: `HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, config.Routes.Remove method should be used for this. To obtain route names you want to delete you may watch for them in debugger.
[image]

Default route name has name '**DefaultApis**'.

So this code works:

```
ServiceConfig.Config.Routes.Remove("DefaultApis");            
ServiceConfig.Config.Routes.Remove("tables");
```

Answer (score 1):

In `App_Start`, you should have a file called `RouteConfig`.

There's a method called `RegisterRoutes` in that class in which you will see pre-configured route mappings.

You can remove those as you see fit.

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

additionnally, if you want to use routing by MVC attributes, you can add the following line:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Comment: I know about RouteConfig, but haven't such file for Azure Mobile Serivce. So there is nothing to remove .